# Delay in showing live view as diffuse content of SCNMaterial for sphere geometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to show a live spherical image using SceneKit. I am using SCNMaterial's diffuse content to show it but there is some delay in showing live view. Following code is my attempt to accomplish it. Please guide if you come across such case.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!
    let scene = SCNScene()


    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.mipFilter = .linear
    material.diffuse.magnificationFilter = .linear
    material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.cullMode = .front

    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 8)
    sphere.segmentCount = 300

    httpConnection.startLiveView { (data) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            material.diffuse.contents = image
        }
    }


    sphere.firstMaterial = material

    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    sphereNode.geometry = sphere

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

in `httpConnection.startLiveView` block I am getting live view's image data.